# How to return a range of elements or arrays from a list using their indices?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a list

```
caches = [[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)],[(11,12,13),(12,13,14),(13,14,15)],[(21,22,23),(22,23,24),(23,24,25)],[(31,32,33),(32,33,34),(33,34,35)]]
```

I want to get rid of the last array such that output is:

```
cache = [[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)],[(11,12,13),(12,13,14),(13,14,15)],[(21,22,23),(22,23,24),(23,24,25)]
```

I have tried following so far:

```
cache=caches[1:L-1]
cache=caches[1,L-1] #L is the length of the list
cache=caches[0:L-1]
```

I saw the documentation but could find exactly what I wanted. What am I missing?

Comment: Indices start at zero

Comment: Fix your rags. There are no arrays here

Comment: caches = [[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)],[(11,12,13),(12,13,14),(13,14,15)],[(21,22,23),(22,23,24),(23,24,25)],[(31,32,33),(32,33,34),(33,34,35)]]
`print(caches[0:3])`-->[[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)], [(11, 12, 13), (12, 13, 14), (13, 14, 15)], [(21, 22, 23), (22, 23, 24), (23, 24, 25)]]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Salio. But actually I want to get rid of the last array. Sorry I have edited the answer.  The length of the list might not be necessarily 4. Can you help me with that?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, you can use the slicing notation to keep everything except the last item: `cache = caches[:-1]`  but But a `better way` is to delete the item directly:`del caches[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
cache = caches[:-1] # ':-1' means everything except the last item
print(cache)
```